# Java execute task on same thread after some delay

Tags: timer, executorservice

I wanted to execute a task on the calling thread only but after some delay

I see Timer API as one option but it creates another thread. What would be the best possible solution

Comment: Are you looking for Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Thread.sleep() is one possible option, but i wanted to know if there are any sophisticated techniques